# Unable to upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04 becuase of nvidia gpg key

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, gnupg

Every time I try `sudo apt update`, I get the error, `GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/ubuntu/amd64  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY`.

I have tried all the suggestions from googling the problem but nothing works.

Now, I just want delete nvidia's keyring completely and force an upgrade. Is there a sure-fire way to do this?

Comment: The general idea for an upgrade is to remove all 3d party repo's . Please disable/remove it and then do the upgrade. After the upgrade you add the new repo for 23.04